# Is there an archived video with commentary of Norway 2015 blitz tournament available on the official or other websites?

Tags: tournament

They have many of top 10 players of the world, two teams of commentators on two different continents, but it seems impossible to (easily) find the archived broadcast on any official websites...

Comment: +1 The tournament was held yesterday and the first round of the real tournament is ongoing, yet the "Livegames" link on tournament web page gives a site showing games form the blitz tournament, and an embedded Youtube video titled "NorwayChess Blitz livestream", which says "Please stand by." The Norway Chess Youtube account doesn't have any stored videos from this year's tournament, and I couldn't find any on Livestream, either. Let's hope they'll make things work before the end of the tournament. (Fortunately you can get the current round broadcast by going to chess24.com directly.)

Answer (score 1):

Blitz video now seems available at http://livestream.com/chess24/norwaychess2015